# SharePoint Canvas app - load screen based on content type

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Situation: SharePoint list with two content types (CTs) - most fields are common, few are unique/exclusive to specific CTs. Plan is to utilize Power Apps canvas app that overwrites default new-edit-view forms for SharePoint items. Already created new Power App "app" with integration, app and screen components - also new screen for other content type.

Goal: when item form is prompted, open screen "assigned" to specific content type. In other words, if I want to open edit form for item with CT "A" load one screen, but if for item with CT "B" - load other. I am looking for solution that would detect CT and pick screen (form?).

[image: screen and tables describing situation]

Problem: how to achieve goal? Is it possible to have on-the-fly evaluation that decides which screen to load? Have tried different methods, no luck so far. Most articles describe how form contains control that user can use to make a switch - not the case here, since evaluation should be done before any form is loaded. I have tried introducing "temporary loader" form, but could not achive auto-redirect to desired screen/form.